# YouTube listsearch filter

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

Simple question, I'm using the google-api-php-client to search youtube for videos and I want to filter the results to only return videos.  The library says you can do this:

> By default, a search result set identifies matching video, channel,
>   and playlist resources, but you can also configure queries to only
>   retrieve a specific type of resource. (search.list)

But I'm unclear as to how.  How should I be modifying the query?

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
    ));
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `type` as `video`, for instance:

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
  'type' => 'video'
));
```

By default, the `type` field is `video, channel, playlist` so you will get all 3 by default.

Comment: euhh can't believe I didn't spot that, I even looked for type as it was phrased "type of resource".  Thanks.